# Unanswered questions

Tags: discussion

I have a number of questions that have either not received any potential answers or the answers do not apply to my SharePoint set up.

I suspect there are no answers to some of these questions. I have seen a similar question here on meta ([Questions which have no answer](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/questions-which-have-no-answer)) but I am loathe to mark my own answer "not possible" as the answer as I don't know for sure they are not possible.

Do I need to just leave these questions hanging around? I can't afford to start bounties on all of them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is rarely "not possible" but rather "not possible without custom code that is probably not worth the effort of developing". Either is a valid answer if it is true, and that can help people who have the same problem. So if it turns out to be impossible by all means say so as an answer. I don't see any problem in leaving questions "hanging around" if they have useful information.

If it turns out that there is some peculiarity or something specific to your environment that is unlikely to occur generally then I would say close it or delete it. For example you have a question "why can't I navigate to my team site" and it turns out the network cable was unplugged by the cleaner - that should be closed because it wouldn't really help anybody else (unless they had a clumsy cleaner).

Remember to up-vote answers if they are helpful - they don't have to be perfect. It encourages people to post valid answers, and if we all do that we increase the chance of getting some answers to these questions.

Comment: True, although it's hard for me to know if my questions are too localised when I'm still a newbie to SharePoint. I just wish if the answer is "not possible without custom code that is probably not worth the effort of developing" that someone would post that as an answer!

Comment: Yes, sometimes that is a useful answer if it saves people from wasting time chasing a unicorn :-)